# DBPath and Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I have restored a snapshot to my EBS and the data resides on a mounted volume. I have access to the volume via /data and the mongo database exists. I have issues trying to access it. The system does not detect the /data/db. When I run mongo it defaults to another db which is empty. I tried running the following:

```
mongod -dbpath /data/db
015-05-07T11:52:06.036+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen():  
 bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket:
 0.0.0.0:27017
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.037+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr 
 already in use
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.545+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal 
 dir=/data/db/journal
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.545+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover
 : no journal files present, no recovery needed
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.700+0000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability 
 thread started
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.701+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal 
 writer thread started
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.763+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB 
 starting : pid=2005 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit 
 host=ip-10-51-186-190

 2015-05-07T11:52:06.764+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.764+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: 
 /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.

 2015-05-07T11:52:06.764+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **       
 We  suggest setting it to 'never'
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.764+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.764+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: 
 /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.764+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        
 We suggest setting it to 'never'
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.764+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.764+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version
 v3.0.2
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.764+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 
 6201872043ecbbc0a4cc169b5482dcf385fc464f
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.764+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL
 version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.764+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info:
  Linux ip-10-229-1-2 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 
 19:11:08
 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49

 2015-05-07T11:52:06.764+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: 
 tcmalloc
 2015-05-07T11:52:06.764+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { 
 storage: { dbPath: "/data/db" } }
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.735+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.735+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: 
 going to close listening sockets...
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.736+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown:
 going to flush diaglog...
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.736+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: 
 going to close sockets...
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.736+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: 
 waiting for fs preallocator...
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.736+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: 
 final commit...
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.741+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] 
 journalCleanup...
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.741+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] 
 removeJournalFiles
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.868+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Terminating 
 durability thread ...
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.941+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal 
 writer thread stopped
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.941+0000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability 
 thread stopped
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.941+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: 
 closing all files...
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.951+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
 closeAllFiles() finished
 2015-05-07T11:53:50.951+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: 
 removing fs lock...
2015-05-07T11:53:50.951+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

I have tried all kinds of attempts and nothing works. I can access the files via ubuntu but mongod just will not access them. I tried stopping starting, I tried rebooting, I tried changing mongod.conf and none of the solutions attempted work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working finally using 
    sudo mongod

That was the only thing that worked.